# Constructor that needs data from asynchronous API call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, constructor, callback

I'm wondering what route I should take to make this code work "as intended." The API call is asynchronous -- so the constructor returns before data is loaded.

```
addSongById: function (songId) {
    var song = new Song(songId);
    console.log(song);
    this.addSong(song);

    if (this.songCount() == 1)
        this.play();

    UserInterface.refresh();
    SongGrid.reload();
},

function Song(songId) {
    $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + songId + '?v=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=?', function (data) {
        this.id = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) { var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8); return v.toString(16); });
        this.songId = songId;
        this.url = "http://youtu.be/" + songId;
        this.name = data.entry.title.$t;
    });
}
```

Is it possible to force the constructor to not return prematurely? Ideally I wouldn't have to pass an arbitrary amount of parameters into the Song constructor and bring information only relevant to Song outside the scope of it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use `$.ajax` instead of `$.get` with option `async: false`. However this will lock execution of every other javascript. And this may be a problem if for example the server won't respond for any reason.

Therefore this is a bad practice. Use callbacks, for example

```
function Song(songId, callback) {
    var self = this;
    $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + songId + '?v=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=?', function (data) {
        self.id = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) { var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8); return v.toString(16); });
        self.songId = songId;
        self.url = "http://youtu.be/" + songId;
        self.name = data.entry.title.$t;
        callback();
    });
}

var song = new Song(songId, function() {
    // The other code goes here.
});
```

Comment: I think this is what I want.. let me try it out, one sec.

Comment: `this` in the `getJSON` callback will not refer to the `Song` instance.

Answer (score 7):

As with most asynchronous operations, I'd use a `Deferred` in this situation; constructors in JS are not obliged to return an instance of themselves:

```
function Song(songId) {
    var song = this;
    var def = new $.Deferred();
    $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + songId + '?v=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=?', function (data) {
        song.id = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) { var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8); return v.toString(16); });
        song.songId = songId;
        song.url = "http://youtu.be/" + songId;
        song.name = data.entry.title.$t;
        def.resolve(song);
    });
    return def.promise();
}

var promise = new Song(songId);
promise.done(function(instance) {
    // you've got a Song instance
});
```

Comment: Way nicer, than the callback solution.

Comment: very old thread I know, but rather then returning the promise, why not to store it in some `this.promise = def.promise();` then on the async callback `def.resolve(this)`? that way the constructor returns the object, and the callback can be chained this way: `var song=new Song(songId); song.promise.done(function(){doWhatever()})`

Comment: @undefinederror makes a very good point. A singleton constructor should never return anything but its own instance

Answer (score 3):

> ...it is a bad practice. A constructor should return an instance of
>   its class, nothing else. It would mess up the new operator and
>   inheritance otherwise.
>
> Moreover, a constructor should only create and initialize a new
>   instance. It should set up data structures and all instance-specific
>   properties, but not execute any tasks. It should be a pure function
>   without side effects if possible, with all the benefits that has.

Ref: [Is it bad practice to have a constructor function return a Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398699/is-it-bad-practice-to-have-a-constructor-function-return-a-promise)

Answer (score 0):

sync call may cause browser to stop responding and some browser may kill you script forcefully.

Jquery has an option while making a request to a URI

> asyncBoolean Default: true
>
> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to
>   true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to
>   false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not
>   support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may
>   temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request
>   is active. As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false is deprecated.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Hope this will be helpful

Regards.

Comment: Mmm, should I be worried about the use of a deprecated parameter?

Comment: i hope you are not using jquery 1.8 as it is not stable yet. but you can use it on 1.7.x safely.